# php get date -1 month

Tags: php, mysql

So here is the situation. In my db table i have a column called expire_date, where i put a certain date for each row. 
So for example the expire date is 28-04-2012

I need a php code that will send a certain user a notice via email that the certain thing that expires on that date is 1 month from expiring. So if today is 28-03-2012, that means that there is only 1 moonth before that thing expires.
I didn't make any code for this because i don't know how to solve the -1 month.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First get the date in one month with php:

```
$myDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( date("Y-m-d") ) ) . "+1 month" ) );
```

Then you can do a select:

```
$result = mysql_query( 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE expire_date BETWEEN NOW AND "' . $myDate . '"' );
```

And there you have an array with all the items who expire in less than one month.
If you want exactly the ones that expire in 1 month:

```
$result = mysql_query( 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE expire_date = "' . $myDate . '"' );
```

I hope this helps

Comment: @Tales you actually should be able to get the same date using 1 less date() function such as: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-d')  . ' +1 month'));`

Comment: @Tales Actually, I guess just `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month'));` right?

Answer (score 42):

```
echo strtotime("-1 day"); //1332864156
echo date("y-m-d",strtotime("-1 day")); // 12-03-27
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 19):

I'm surprised this answer is missing here:

```
$oneMonthAgo = new \DateTime('1 month ago');
echo $oneMonthAgo->format('Y-m-d');
```

Today is `2019-01-28`. The code above outputs `2018-12-28`

Here it is live to play with: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad457f441719c6b9f68dc646445aac86a3f7f7a0

Comment: Thank you John, this is the best answer imo.

Answer (score 11):

Simply ;

```
    $WeekAgo = strtotime("-1 week"); //A week before today
    $MonthAgo = strtotime("-1 month"); //A month before today
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should do that in SQL rather than PHP no?

If you want to do in in PHP, here is a cleaner way than @Expert want to be

```
$date = new DateTime();//now 
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');// P[eriod] 1 M[onth]
$date->sub($interval);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @Mikhail you should use `=` so that you only retrieve the record once. You don't want to be spamming your users everyday for the whole of the month running up to the expire_date -

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE expire_date = CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

If your expire_date contains a DATETIME as opposed to a DATE value you should use something like -

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE expire_date BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MONTH + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user, email FROM tbl WHERE expire_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Notice that I use `=` and not less than, because if you just compare that it's less than one month, then you will be emailing the users every day during the last month.

Comment: This selects records that expired one month ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `ADDDATE()` function in your MySQL Query.

```
> SELECT ADDDATE(  '28-03-2012', INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
28-04-2012
```

More about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate).

If you have an index on your `expire_date` column, this can be done quite fast if you query for entries with a `WHERE` statement like:

```
WHERE expire_date = ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

(More about `CURDATE()` right [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate))

If you do that **every day exactly once** it will only select all people at max once and not send them the email twice since it only selects those that are exactly 1 month away from their expire date.

Of course this works without any additional care about the specific representation of dates if you use a **DATE fieldtype** in your MySQL table.

Answer (score 1):

How to get one month back date in php

```
<?php
  $d = strtotime("-1 Months");
  echo date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $d);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following codes worked for me, hope be useful to others with similar issue:

```
$thisMonth = date('Y-m');
$nextMonth = date('Y-m', strtotime('+1 month'));
$previousMonth = date('Y-m', strtotime('-1 month'));

$today = date('Y-m-d');
$nextDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day'));
$previousDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'));

php 8.1.4
```

The code output:

```
"2023-01" // $thisMonth
"2023-02" // $nextMonth
"2022-12" // $previousMonth

"2023-01-03" // $today
"2023-01-04" // $nextDay
"2023-01-02" // $previousDay
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to turn your date string into unix time and then do a select datediff. (I assume you´re using sql).

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (SELECT datediff(now(),your-date-in-unixtime) > 30)
```

Comment: You should avoid using functions on the fields that you are trying to filter on as it renders indices unusable.

Answer (score -1):

For the SQL you can use the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM   tablename
WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y/%m/%d') = (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: You should always avoid doing it like this. Using the `DATE_FORMAT()` on the DATE/DATETIME field you want to filter by will render any index useless.